# Need clear info on creating custom statistics in gemfire?

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I need to capture some of the metrics which is not currently provided by Gemfire in the Mbeans. And i came across the statistics to capture the same, but there is no clear docs regarding developing custom statistics . Please let me know, how to enhance custom statistics for capturing additional data in gemfire.

Answer (score 1):

The javadocs for [StatisticsFactory](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/953f1eebcb0a1615bc761b684463fe890abe5692/geode-lucene/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/cache/lucene/internal/filesystem/FileSystemStats.java) has some good information on creating a custom statistics.

You can also look at some examples of statistics usage in the geode codebase. For example, here a class which wraps an instance of Statistics and provides public methods to update it: [FileSystemStats.java](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/953f1eebcb0a1615bc761b684463fe890abe5692/geode-lucene/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/cache/lucene/internal/filesystem/FileSystemStats.java).